# AWS S3.waitFor() method, does it go to err block for every fail retry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

as we know, this method try 20 attempts at 5sec interval, so my question is for every fail retry, does it go err block? here is sample code snnipet

```
s3.waitFor('objectExists', params, function(err, data) {
  if (err){ 
   console.log(err);
   }
  else{
   console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#waitFor-property):

> The final callback or 'complete' event will be fired only when the resource is either in its final state or the waiter has timed out and stopped polling for the final state.

In other words, the callback will only be called once, so the answer to your question is no. Either `console.log(err)` or `console.log(data)` will run, and only once.